# Как сделать кастомное поле CollectionType и вывести туда дополнительную информацию&

Tags: php, symfony2

Здравствуйте!

Я делаю страницу редактирование заказа, и на этой странице должна быть возможность добавлять товары в заказ. Соответственно есть 2 сущности Order и OrderProduct. Один заказ может иметь множество товаров, один товар ссылается только 1 заказ.

Сущность Order:

```
// src/Shop/CartBundle/Entity/Order.php

namespace Shop\CartBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Shop\CartBundle\Entity\Repository\OrderRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`order`")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProduct", mappedBy="order")
     */
    protected $products;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $total = 0;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @NotBlank
     */
    protected $customer_type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Length(
     *  min = 5,
     *  max = 255
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Email
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Length(
     *  max = 16
     * )
     */
    protected $telephone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $private_address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $company_address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $company_real_address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $company_mail_address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $comment;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $inn;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $kpp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $okpo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $ogrn;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $rcount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $kcount;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $bank;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $bik;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     * @NotBlank
     */
    protected $taxation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $org_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $delivery;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $payment;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Status", inversedBy="orders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="status", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_created")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_updated")
     */
    protected $updated;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();

        $this->setCreated(new \Datetime());
        $this->setUpdated(new \Datetime());
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setUpdatedValue()
    {
        $this->setUpdated(new \Datetime());
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set total
     *
     * @param string $total
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    protected function setTotal()
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach($this->products as $product)
        {
            $total += $product->getPrice();
        }

        $this->total = $total;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get total
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->total;
    }

    /**
     * Set customerType
     *
     * @param string $customerType
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCustomerType($customerType)
    {
        $this->customer_type = $customerType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get customerType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomerType()
    {
        return $this->customer_type;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set telephone
     *
     * @param string $telephone
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setTelephone($telephone)
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telephone
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTelephone()
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    /**
     * Set privateAddress
     *
     * @param string $privateAddress
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setPrivateAddress($privateAddress = '')
    {
        $this->private_address = $privateAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get privateAddress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrivateAddress()
    {
        return $this->private_address;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyAddress
     *
     * @param string $companyAddress
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCompanyAddress($companyAddress = '')
    {
        $this->company_address = $companyAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyAddress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompanyAddress()
    {
        return $this->company_address;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyRealAddress
     *
     * @param string $companyRealAddress
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCompanyRealAddress($companyRealAddress = '')
    {
        $this->company_real_address = $companyRealAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyRealAddress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompanyRealAddress()
    {
        return $this->company_real_address;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyMailAddress
     *
     * @param string $companyMailAddress
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCompanyMailAddress($companyMailAddress = '')
    {
        $this->company_mail_address = $companyMailAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyMailAddress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompanyMailAddress()
    {
        return $this->company_mail_address;
    }

    /**
     * Set comment
     *
     * @param string $comment
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setComment($comment = '')
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get comment
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    /**
     * Set inn
     *
     * @param string $inn
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setInn($inn = '')
    {
        $this->inn = $inn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get inn
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInn()
    {
        return $this->inn;
    }

    /**
     * Set kpp
     *
     * @param string $kpp
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setKpp($kpp = '')
    {
        $this->kpp = $kpp;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get kpp
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKpp()
    {
        return $this->kpp;
    }

    /**
     * Set okpo
     *
     * @param string $okpo
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setOkpo($okpo = '')
    {
        $this->okpo = $okpo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get okpo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOkpo()
    {
        return $this->okpo;
    }

    /**
     * Set ogrn
     *
     * @param string $ogrn
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setOgrn($ogrn = '')
    {
        $this->ogrn = $ogrn;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ogrn
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOgrn()
    {
        return $this->ogrn;
    }

    /**
     * Set rcount
     *
     * @param string $rcount
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setRcount($rcount = '')
    {
        $this->rcount = $rcount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rcount
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRcount()
    {
        return $this->rcount;
    }

    /**
     * Set kcount
     *
     * @param string $kcount
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setKcount($kcount = '')
    {
        $this->kcount = $kcount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get kcount
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKcount()
    {
        return $this->kcount;
    }

    /**
     * Set bank
     *
     * @param string $bank
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setBank($bank = '')
    {
        $this->bank = $bank;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bank
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBank()
    {
        return $this->bank;
    }

    /**
     * Set bik
     *
     * @param string $bik
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setBik($bik = '')
    {
        $this->bik = $bik;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bik
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBik()
    {
        return $this->bik;
    }

    /**
     * Set taxation
     *
     * @param string $taxation
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setTaxation($taxation = '')
    {
        $this->taxation = $taxation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get taxation
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTaxation()
    {
        return $this->taxation;
    }

    /**
     * Set orgName
     *
     * @param string $orgName
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setOrgName($orgName = '')
    {
        $this->org_name = $orgName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get orgName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOrgName()
    {
        return $this->org_name;
    }

    /**
     * Set delivery
     *
     * @param string $delivery
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setDelivery($delivery = '')
    {
        $this->delivery = $delivery;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get delivery
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDelivery()
    {
        return $this->delivery;
    }

    /**
     * Set payment
     *
     * @param string $payment
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setPayment($payment = '')
    {
        $this->payment = $payment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get payment
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPayment()
    {
        return $this->payment;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param \Shop\CartBundle\Entity\Product $product
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function addProduct(\Shop\CartBundle\Entity\OrderProduct $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;

        $this->setTotal();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param \Shop\CartBundle\Entity\Product $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(\Shop\CartBundle\Entity\OrderProduct $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
}
```

Сущность OrderProduct:

```
<?php

// src/Shop/CartBundle/Entity/OrderProduct.php

namespace Shop\CartBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_product")
 */
class OrderProduct
    {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
     */
    protected $price_retail;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return OrderProduct
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param string $price
     *
     * @return OrderProduct
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set priceRetail
     *
     * @param string $priceRetail
     *
     * @return OrderProduct
     */
    public function setPriceRetail($priceRetail)
    {
        $this->price_retail = $priceRetail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get priceRetail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPriceRetail()
    {
        return $this->price_retail;
    }

    /**
     * Set order
     *
     * @param \Shop\CartBundle\Entity\Order $order
     *
     * @return OrderProduct
     */
    public function setOrder(\Shop\CartBundle\Entity\Order $order = null)
    {
        $this->order = $order;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get order
     *
     * @return \Shop\CartBundle\Entity\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->order;
    }

    /**
     * Set product
     *
     * @param \Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Product $product
     *
     * @return OrderProduct
     */
    public function setProduct(\Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Product $product = null)
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get product
     *
     * @return \Shop\CatalogBundle\Entity\Product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

Используя CollectionType я могу вывести список добавленных товаров в заказ.
Конфигурация поля:

```
$builder->add('products', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'        => TextType::class,
    'entry_options'     => array()
));
```

Вот что получается после рендеринга поля в шаблоне:

```
<label for="order_products_1" class="required">1</label>    
<input type="text" id="order_products_1" name="order[products][1]" required="required" class="test" value="Product 2" />
```

Как видно в label подставляется порядковый номер сущности в массиве $products, а в input название товара.

Такие меня мучают вопросы:
1. Каким образом можно изменить данные подставляемые в value input'a? Чтобы вместо названия товара использовался его id.
2. В идеале я хочу сделать такой формат отображения каждого элемента в этом CollectionType:

```
input{id товара} - {Название товара} - {цена} - input{количество}
```

Как мне кажется нужно сделать новый тип как сервис, который будет наследником CollectionType, элементы которого формировать в сервисе. Но все же мне не понятно как сделать дополнительные инпуты, для редактирования количества каждого товара.
Или существует какой-то более правильный вариант решения данной задачи.

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь или совет!